# Cast Variable to Class

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm

It may be an odd question, but in all our systems we use a loader class to get us the class back:

```
$Class = core::load('ClassName'); //returns an instance of the class ClassName
```

This may not be the best approach, but as I said it's been here forever so changing it would be a huge thing to do. And besides it works perfectly for us. THe only problem is that PHPStorm doesn't recognise the `$Class` as an instance of `ClassName`. Is there any way to do something similair to this cast in php?

```
$Class = (ClassName)core::load('ClassName');
```

Comment: I use PHPStorm too, version 8.0.2, and if I write e.g. `$template = BS_Lib_Template::getInstance($rTemplate->id);`, `$template` is recognized. There must be something wrong with your PHPStorm settings i think

Comment: Quick note: common approach is to name classes starting with capital letter, while instances, variables etc start with lowercased, so I'd suggest refactoring as it would help reading the source. Your line could then read `$myclass = (ClassName)Core::load('ClassName');`

Comment: @YUNOWORK Your case is completely different. In your case IDE may detected return type automatically (or you can describe return type manually via PHPDoc's `@return MyClass`). In OP's case it's a factory where the same method returns instance of different class based on parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in PhpStorm:

```
/**
 * @var YourClass $Class
 */
$Class = core::load('ClassName');
```

Comment: This is how I do it, too. You can also do it on a single line: `/** @var ClassName $class */` to save space.

Answer (score 1):

use @var [type] [variable] to let PHPStorm know the class type

/** @var ClassName $Class */ 
$Class = core::load('ClassName');

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if your class is instance of YourClass just [using it](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php):

```
$obj = new A();
if ($obj instanceof A) {
    // do something...
}
```